# Can I get rid of fake messages from the preview?

Tags: sms, stock-email-app

On a Galaxy tablet, underneath "Messages 3 x 2", or "Email 3 x 2", some fake messages are appearing.

> John Doe
>   Tomorrow's event
>
> Marissa Haro
>   [illegible]
>
> Raye
>   Re: Re: How's it going in Seoul?
>   Sweetheart. I miss you so much. Having a ...
>
> Zuno Du
>   Here is our plan :)

and

> Peter Leiagh
>   OMG! I didn't know it! Why didn't you tell me?
>
> Sam Martin
>   I will never gonna tell you :-p
>
> John Smith
>   You're BACK!!!
>
> Marissa Haro
>   Hello. Here is the [illegible]
>
> Eva green
>   This is the last remind message

Based on these messages featuring [John Smith](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/John_Smith), [John Doe](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/John_Doe_(disambiguation)) (I assume this was intentional, though it could be intended as someone with a surname of [Doe](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Doe) choosing an English name of "John"), and [Eva Green](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/evergreen), I suspect that they were intentionally fake names.

Clicking on the preview item opened it up, and it was empty.

I wiped emails from the GMail application, and wiped the tablet clean, prior to seeing these fake messages.

The tablet isn't intended to send or receive text messages, though it received a few in the past prior to me wiping it.

How can I stop these fake messages appearing?

Comment: Alternative question title: "How can I stop Raye from saying that she misses me in Seoul?"

Comment: Have you noticed the number or the email address from which those messages came?

Comment: If possible, just disable the app.